# Install4j: Delete files in certain directory below the installation directory

Tags: java, install4j

My problem is: 
In the `sys.contentDir` we have the `libs` directory. And in this directory we have the `client` and `server` dir. (Actually we have more, but let's keep it simple for the sake of brevity.)

So when we do an update installation, we want to delete all jars/files in those directories (`client`/`server`), **but not the sub-directories** which have the name `ext` and `plugin`.

To make it a bit more easy to understand:

### [image: the file tree]

So everything in the outer rectangle is to be uninstalled, but everything in the inner rectangle is to be left as is.

So, normally you would use the `Uninstall files` action, but that doesn't work in this particular case for two reasons. 
1. You can specify for a directory that is will be uninstalled, but it only works if there is no sub-directory below that remains (what we explicitly want).
2. You could also specify for every single file if it should be deleted. But we are not able to provide a file list (of the required jars) because it is subject to change.

So the question is: How do you best solve the problem?
(Solution provided below!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is to implement an additonal step `Delete files and directories` during the Uninstall process.

It is configured with this directory: 
`${installer:sys.contentDir}` which is the platform-independent place where the program is installed with install4j.

And the Java code is:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    return false;
}

File directory = new File(context.getInstallationDirectory(), "/lib");
if (!directory.exists()) {
    return false;
}

List<File> subDirs = new ArrayList<>();
File[] delinquents = directory.listFiles();
for (File delinquent : delinquents) {
    if (delinquent.isDirectory()) {
        subDirs.add(delinquent);   
    }
}

for (File sub : subDirs) {

    File[] filesInLib = sub.listFiles();
    for(File theFile : filesInLib) {
        if (theFile.equals(file))
        {
            Util.logInfo(null, "Delete " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

It actually works perfectly. But I wanted to know if there is a better solution, like where you only have to configure this stuff without using any code. (I want to not use a lot of code snippets to keep it maintainable.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Directory filter script" property of the "Delete files and directories" action and set it to

```
File contentDirectory = context.getContentDirectory();
return !directory.equals(new File(contentDirectory, "lib/client/ext")) &&
    !directory.equals(new File(contentDirectory, "lib/client/plugin"));
```

Comment: Now I still have one problem: I have put some extra jars into the `lib/client` directory. They are not deleted with your solution.